# Loft splines Does not close object,Animation nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

I have 2 closed curves and I connected them using the Loft splines node,
But the resulted mesh have a face missing.

How can I close it?

[image: mesh]

Comment: That is a bug. I need some more time to fix it. Will report back when it is fixed. https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues/573

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in the Animation Nodes addon. The problem appeared when you tried to loft cyclic splines.

The bug is fixed now. Please download a new version (uninstall the old version at first).

[image]

Btw a quick tip: when the normals of the output object show in the wrong direction it helps when you insert a "Reverse List" node as shown in the example.